# Audio Voice Changer using Matlab

Tags: java, ios

I am currently working on Audio Voice Changer in Matlab for DSP Semester project. So far I have been able to read wav files using wavread in Matlab. However its not sufficient that i read only wav files.I want to read all audio files So to read all audio files please tell me the command to read.

Answer (score 0):

[audioread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html#btiabil-3) allows you to read many audio formats in MATLAB